# Jupyter Notebook does not sync with PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jupyter

Suppose that I create an .ipynb in PyCharm, and then start an IPython Notebook kernel. Then if I modify the notebook in the browser, how do I get the changes back to PyCharm?

There is a 'synchronize' function when I right-click the file name in PyCharm but it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Same here. Really a pain.

Comment: simply restart the notebook server

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is:

- Once started the Jupyter server started, make sure the file edited through Jupyter is closed in Pycharm
- Save the Jupyter Notebook: 'Save and checkpoint' method
- In Pycharm, synchronize the notebook
- The notebook can be now opened and the changes appear

I guess the reason of the error is that while the notebook is opened is pycharm, pycharm edit it and overwrite at anytime the modications done by the jupyter server. Yet, it is only a guess, I have no certainty about the origin of such behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

For me, invalidating the PyCharm cache worked.

1. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart…
2. Invalidate and Restart. (Just Invalidate might also work.)

Comment: This fixed an issue for me where the notebook preview pane was blank/unresponsive.

Comment: w/a for issue when changes in markdown cell doesn't recognized by git

Answer (score 1):

Try to save using checkpoints. You can always go to the last checkpoint you added

Answer (score 1):

In the browser, go to File, select Save and Checkpoint. It should appear a window saying: "The notebook file has changed on disk since the last time we opened or saved it. Do you want to overwrite the file on disk with the version open here, or load the version on disk (reload the page) ?"

Then press overwrite, and the changes are overwritten to the file on your pc. Apparently the syncro it's not realtime (I guess this is a bug, since a window pops up in pycharm, but it seems useless), if you have your ipynb open, you should close it and reopen it to see the update.

Answer (score -1):

To synchronize Jupyter with PyCharm, you must to add in Pycharm the path of the Jupyter interpreter.

For example, if you use an Anaconda/Conda environment and Python language, you must add the path of the Python that uses Anaconda in:

1. File > Settings > Project Interpreter
2. Click the '*' button (screw) > Add > Conda Environment
3. Choose the correspondent path (e.g. '~/anaconda/bin/python')
4. OK > Apply